# Is there an easy way to convert a Javascript Object into "name": "Fred", "value": "Blue" style pairs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm positive this question must have been covered before, but I can quite find it. So....

I have an object like so

```
Object
name: Fred
lastname: Jones
city: Los Angeles
```

I'd like to use Javascript to convert it to a string that looks like this:

```
//Do want this
[
 {"name": "name", "value": "Fred"},
 {"name": "lastname", "value": "Jones"},
 {"name": "city", "value": "Los Angeles"}
]
```

All of the examples I've found use JSON.parse() to get a result that looks like this (which I don't want):

```
//Don't want this
[
 {"name": "Fred", "lastname": "Jones", "city": "Los Angeles"}
]
```

I'm working with another developer who says this is how Jquery parses objects (EDIT- he's using $serializeArray(), so perhaps JQuery has a method to help me with this.

Any ideas would be most welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the advantage of the format you want? In short, you just need to split key-value pairs into (name-key, value-value) objects. Should be simple with a simple loop.

Comment: Why do you want the names of the properties?

Comment: Objects don't need to be parsed.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. There is no advantage to this. I hate it. I don't want to do it like this. But an earlier developer was saving data using the Jquery serialize() method and now I'm forced to save my data in the same assinine way. I have manually coded a loop but thought there might be an underscore method I was missing.

Comment: Not entirely sure what the other developer you're working with is talking about, their statement about jQuery definitely doesn't sound correct.

Comment: And just to be clear the the way you want you codeo to look like isn't a "String" its an array of objects.

Comment: Can you say "refactor" real fast 20 times :)

Comment: I'm going to revise my previous statement: There's the `.serializeArray()` jQuery function that provides that format, but it only works for form elements, not objects. That may be how they went about getting this format in the first place, but there's no logical reason I can think of to *save* that.

Comment: Correction- the developer was using serializeArray()

Comment: How exactly are you passing the data back to the server? If you're passing it as an object to the `data` parameter of an ajax request, your current structure will pass it the same way serializeArray's structure will.

Comment: Thanks Kevin B, it's not ajax, but some Salesforce madness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This conversion calls for iterating through the properties of the source object and accumulating entries in a result array.

```
function toList( obj ) {
  var rv = [], k;
  for (k in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k))
      rv.push({ name: k, value: obj[k] });
  }
  return rv;
}

var list = toList( myObject );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr = []
for (var key in object_name) {
    arr.push({'name': key, 'value': object_name[key]})
}
```

Loop through the keys and add it to the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the object properties and create the array

```
var a = array();
for (p in obj) {
    a.push({'name': p, 'value': obj[p]});
}
```

This should get the structure that you want.

Comment: Thanks Schleis- much appreciation for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it in a simple `for..in` loop.

```
var yourObject = { name: "Fred", lastname: "Jones", city: "Los Angeles" },
    parsed = [];

for(var i in yourObject){
   parsed.push({ name: i, value: yourObject[i]})
}
```